# how can set or change global variable value at runtime in laravel

Tags: laravel

I used global Variable  and shared it in all views but when I try to change its value, it doesn't work . also I tried use ***`config`*** file but when I change its value its doesn't work .
please help me;
thanks
my config file name is langauge and its content is:    `<?php return [ 'lng' => 'english', ];`

I want to change lng to 'arabic' or 'spanich'
I tied this statement but it doesn't change
`config()->set('config.langauge.lng', 'arabic');`

Comment: if you want to save a global var for language it would be better if you used the locale global var, check this link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I used translation string when I change **locale** in Route it changed , but doesn't change in views  this is the code in route    `
Route::get('/langauge/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    if (! in_array($locale, ['en', 'ar'])) {
        abort(400);
    }
echo App::currentLocale();  // to test current local the output is en the old value

    App::setLocale($locale);

    echo App::currentLocale(); // to test current local the output is ar the new value

    echo __('dir');
    return view('welcome');
})->name('langauge');
    `

Answer (score 1):

To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the `config` helper:

your code should be like:

```
config(['langauge.lng' => 'arabic']);
```

Comment: when print  config value at controller it changed    'echo "<pre>";
        print_r(config('langauge.lng'));
        echo "</pre>";'    but it doesn't effect at views

Comment: maybe `php artisan cache:clear` can help